# How to make a desktop software update with Windows Update?

Tags: windows, windows-update

What I'm looking for is something like Ubuntu's PPAs: I want a desktop software from my company to update alongside with the Windows Update System, whenever I release a new version. Does Windows Update have an API for that, or something?

PS.: The software is made in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Update only delivers updates to Microsoft software, and drivers certified by the MS hardware labs. MS will not push out your updates. You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Well, that was fast, sad, and accurate. Thanks.

Comment: If you were MS, would let any Tom, Dick and Harry push out lord knows what software under the banner of Windows Update? I think for good reasons they won't. Users would rebel.

Comment: You're right. That wouldn't be suitable for most users. But talking about users with a little more experience, asking for user permission would solve that partially... Almost every Linux have something like this, and they review and accept packages to their repository according to necessity and maturity of the package. Ubuntu's PPAs are a good example of a working API for software updates.

Comment: But my opinion won't change Microsoft. Lol